# how to select 2 select statments in VBA scripts

Tags: vba, excel

in the below VBA I have one select statments with one table but I want multiple select statements results need to capture in excel.

```
Sub extract()

    'usedrows = Sheets("Batch_Creation").Range("A" & Sheets("Batch_Creation").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox usedrows

    Dim cn As Object
    Dim uid1, pass1, srvrnm
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Dim cmdSQLData As Object
    Set cmdSQLData = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    uid1 = "XXXXX"
    pass1 = "XXXXX"
    srvrnm = "XXXXX"

    On Error GoTo err1
    cn.Open "Driver=Teradata; DBCName=" & srvrnm & ";uid=" & uid1 & ";AUTHENTICATION=ldap;pwd=" & pass1 & "; Trusted_Connection=True"


    Set cmdSQLData.ActiveConnection = cn
    'MsgBox ("1")
    On Error Resume Next
 query1 = "select top 20 * from DBC.TABLES;"   ---first select statements
query2 = "select count(*) from DBC.TABLES;"   ---2nd  select statements
query3 = "select * from DBC.TABLES where columnname="santosh";"   ---3rd  select statements
    'MsgBox query1

        cmdSQLData.CommandText = query1
        cmdSQLData.CommandTimeout = 0
        Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()

    Dim r As Integer 'Row
    Dim c As Integer 'Column

    For c = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        'This will start on Row 1, Column A (due to + 1) and place all the field headers
        Sheet1.Cells(1, c + 1).Value = rs.Fields(c).Name
    Next c
    r = 2 'We'll start on Row 3
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For c = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            'c + 1 means we're starting on Column 1 (A)
            'If we wanted to start in Column d, we would use c + 4
            Sheet1.Cells(r, c + 1).Value = rs.Fields(c)
        Next
        r = r + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
      Set rs = Nothing

    'Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    'rs.Clear

    err1:

    End Sub
```

How can I call multiple select statements in the above scripts

```
query2 = "select count(*) from DBC.TABLES;"   ---2nd  select statements
query3 = "select * from DBC.TABLES where columnname="santosh";"   ---3rd
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem using a recordset for each query?

*rs1* for *query1*

*rs2* for *query2*

*rs3* for *query3*

Another way - you collect the data for your recordset via executing query1, then you do all the stuff you want (copying, pasting, ...).

Afterwards you change *cmdSQLData.CommandText* to *query2*, do all the stuff like above.

Again you change the *CommandText* to *query3*.

Comment: Looking at the queries, you could union 1 and 3, with an indentifier to say which was which, but you'd need more than 1 recordset pass to do it all.  You could add the extra fields to the count so if there were 4 fields in the table select count(*),'' as dummy1, '' as dummy2 and so on, then you could union them all, but i'd use the approach above, it will offer you the recordset functions on each in turn also.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion..i want to display the table name and count of that particular table in my above code